# Last row returns incorrect value in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with 33000+ rows. When i do a insert query it only returns 126+ `(auto_increment)`.

```
$student_sql = "INSERT INTO students (
            `referrer_id`,
            `enrolment_date`,
            `tertiary`,
            `education`,
            `status`,
            `date_added`) VALUES (
            '".database_safe($insertED)."',
            '".database_safe($enrolment_date)."',
            '".database_safe($tertiary)."',
            '".database_safe($education)."',
            '1',
            NOW())";

            if (database_queryModify($student_sql,$studentID)) {

            echo $studentID  // This returns the incorrect Last ID. 
            }
```

My ID in my table is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT` and my table is a `MyIsam`.

So the insert fails because the last `ID` is already there.

UPDATE:

```
  function database_queryModify($sql,&$insertId)
  {
    global $db, $SECTION;

    $result = mysql_query($sql,$db);

    if (!$result) {
        if (mysql_error()) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                echo 'Could not query:' . mysql_error().'\n';
                echo '<br />SQL: '.$sql.'\n';
                exit();
            } else {
                LogError($SECTION,81,mysql_error().' | SQL: '.$sql);
            }
        }
    }

    $insertId = mysql_insert_id();

    return mysql_affected_rows();
  }
```

Comment: Is my tablel maybe locking up? due to the high number of current rows?

Comment: Are we somehow supposed to know what the bleep "database_queryModify()" is?

Comment: You can alter the table AUTO_INCREMENT and set the start to the last + 1.

Comment: No its returning around 120 + 1 everytime i try, but i have over 33000 rows

Comment: Does that mean that the number of rows affected is 120 + 1? or is it the id?

Comment: it returns 121, and if i run the insert again, it then returns 122. and so on. ( no rows are affected because the id 122eg is already there)

Comment: inserts don't return rows, selects do ?

Comment: @dagon please look at the code above. Im returning the mysql_insert_id :)

Comment: its not a smallint is it?

Comment: no int(11)  and the reference in the table shows Next autoindex 33,621. Which is right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. It was a Index set!  mysql_insert_id() was fine!

Answer (score 0):

you should find the `MAX(id)` and then do the following query

```
  ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = max_id +1;
```

Comment: The question is how to return the correct `insert_id`, not how to "update" the index to be what we think it should be. So far the table works fine (at least no other problems were mentioned in the question)

Answer (score 0):

This link validates what @DevZer0 proposes [AUTO_INCREMENT Handling in InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html), yet it doesn't explain why your table is not working as expected.

Under normal conditions MySQL the driver would find the `auto_increment` id is wrong and act accordingly:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE test AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO test VALUES (0,'after alter table');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Your table may need a check: [`CHECK TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/check-table.html) and [`SHOW TABLE STATUS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html)

If your table keeps giving you problems, try asking a question at https://dba.stackexchange.com/ with details of your tables.

---

Original answer:

From [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) documentation:

> Caution
>
> `mysql_insert_id()` will convert the return type of the native MySQL C API function `mysql_insert_id()` to a type of `long` (named `int` in PHP). If your `AUTO_INCREMENT` column has a column type of `BIGINT` (64 bits) the conversion may result in an incorrect value. Instead, use the internal MySQL SQL function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in an SQL query. For more information about PHP's maximum integer values, please see the integer documentation.

What happens if you run a new query `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` instead of using `mysql_insert_id()`?

```
function db_last_insert_id ($db) {
    $insert_id = 0;
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()',$db);

    if ($result) {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        mysql_free_result($result);

        $insert_id = $row[0];
    }

    return $insert_id;
}

function database_queryModify ($sql,&$insertId) {
    global $db, $SECTION;

    $result = mysql_query($sql,$db);

    if (!$result) {
        if (mysql_error()) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                echo 'Could not query:' . mysql_error().'\n';
                echo '<br />SQL: '.$sql.'\n';
                exit();
            }
            else {
                LogError($SECTION,81,mysql_error().' | SQL: '.$sql);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * mysql_insert_id misses the "$db" argument here
     */
    // $insertId = mysql_insert_id();

    $insertId = db_last_insert_id($db);

    return mysql_affected_rows();
}
```

Comment: @Ast Going to try this quick! Thanks

Comment: you have to make an edit to your question, i can't remove the downvote otherwise